# Using a do while loop correctly?

Tags: c, loops, scanf, do-while

My conditions are as follows :

- If the value of userIncome is entered more than 400000, show error.
- Similarly, if the value is less than 500, show error.

Repeat the loop until a correct value is entered.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#define minINCOME 500.00
#define maxINCOME 400000.00

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float userIncome ;


    printf("+--------------------------+\n"
           "+   Wish List Forecaster   |\n"
           "+--------------------------+\n");

   

    do
    {
        printf("Enter your monthly NET income: $");
        scanf(" %.2lf", &userIncome);

        if (userIncome < 500)
        {
            printf("ERROR: You must have a consistent monthly income of at least $500.00\n");
        }

        if (userIncome > 40000)
        {
            printf("ERROR: Liar! I'll believe you if you enter a value no more than $400000.00\n");
        }
    } while (userIncome >= maxINCOME && userIncome <= minINCOME);




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would the `userIncome` be `>= maxINCOME` __and__ `<= minINCOME` at the same time?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @ran By the way what is the relation between 400000 (#define maxINCOME 400000.00) and 40000 used in an if statement?

Comment: @tkausl i improved that, sorry about that but, still it gets into infinite loop if i does this  
 ` while( (userIncome <= maxINCOME || userIncome >= minINCOME));`

Comment: You just inverted the expression. Think about the logic again, __when__ exactly should this loop run again?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it still isnt working

Comment: @tkausl    while( (userIncome >= maxINCOME || userIncome <= minINCOME));

Comment: @tkausl still goes in an infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters this named constant

```
#define maxINCOME 400000.00
```

differs from the constant used in this if statement

```
 if (userIncome > 40000)
```

and in this condition

```
while (userIncome >= maxINCOME && userIncome <= minINCOME);
```

Secondly for object of the type float like this

```
float userIncome ;
```

you need to use the conversion specifier `f` instead of `lf`

```
scanf(" %f", &userIncome);
```

And the condition should be written like

```
while (userIncome >= maxINCOME || userIncome <= minINCOME);
```

And in if statements you need to use the defined named constants as for example

```
if (userIncome >= maxINCOME)
               ^^
```

Comment: And the code should check that the `scanf()` succeeds before using the value reputedly entered.

Comment: it still goes in infinite loop @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @ran I have updated the call of scanf.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thanks for your help, i need another help, i mean i wanna create something that promts for the user to input a value, but if the val is less than 1 and more than 5 it should say error, i can do that, but at the same time it should also do that if the user inputs 3 then it should ask something about those 3 items three separate times. i cant explain because stackoverflow wouldnt let me ask another question untill 90 mins